# Cache Blocking Optimization Technique

Tags: c++, optimization, caching, memory

I can not find good explanation for the cache blocking concept, but I understand why we would want to do cache blocking for matrix multiplication.

but if I have a code like this (I tried simplifying the code as much as possible)

```
void func(double *array, double *array2)
for(int i = 0; i <1000; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j <1000; j++){
        for(int k = 0; k <1000; k++){
            int index = (i*10) + ( (20*j) +k) 
            array[index] = compute(array2[index]);
        }
    }
}
```

How can cache blocking be useful here?

Comment: It is unclear why you don't loop once from 0 to 30970 and instead have billion of iterations.

Comment: Please provide [mre].

Comment: For your example code; do you have to care about the arrays overlapping? If you don't have to care about overlapping it can/should be optimized down to a `for(int index = 0; index <= 30969; index++) { array[index] = compute(array2[index]); }` where the cache blocking concept is useless because it's a nice linear access pattern where nothing is used twice. If you do have to care about overlapping (e.g. `array2 == &array[10]`) it becomes an entire world of pain where any attempt at applying cache blocking will probably break everything.

Answer (score 0):

Very simplistically, the computer has two memories: one is fast and scarse (SDRAM) and the other is slow and plentiful (DDR). We have gigabytes of DDR and just a few Megabytes of SDRAM. In fact there are more types but that would be complex to explain - you can read more [here](https://people.freebsd.org/%7Elstewart/articles/cpumemory.pdf).

What the computer does is to use the fast memory to work temporarily so you dont have to access the big memory all the time. It is like cooking - you get the pans you need, cook your meal then in the end you put all back. If you have to be getting and putting pans away frequently, your work will be slow.

Same thing with memory, you need to place your data very close to each other in the micro scale. Make so you touch only a small range of a few megabytes first, then move to the next block etc.

In the loop above you are sort of doing that already - the inner loop `k` is already the most together in memory. If the `k` loop was outside `i` and `j` then that would be very bad for performance.

You can see that just by exchanging the like `k` with line `j` incurs in a huge loss of performance. You can see the more `k` is in the outside, the slower the performance becomes.

[image]

Link to quickbench: https://quick-bench.com/q/FG4aPSRbF5nuNHsVugL44nMNT-s